# Equation of a Sphere: question on squaring consecutive sphere radius

Tags: 3d, spheres, spherical-geometry

The equation for a sphere produces the following graphs and I have questions on them.  I consecutively squared the radius of a sphere and graphed at an offset of the radius.  As shown below, the spheres touch at a point.  Is there a theorem that describes how the spheres of squared radius touch at a point between them?

I considered graphing in 2D to compare circles of $x,y$ at coordinate $\theta$, however couldn't figure out how to find the how to graph the second circle at the same angle where the first touches.

Equation for a Sphere in Cartesian Coordinates:

$x = x_0 + r sin(\theta)cos(\phi)$, $y = y_0 + rsin(\theta)sin(\phi)$, $z = z_0 + r cos(\phi)$

Equations:
[image: a]

Graphs:
[image: b]
[image: c]

Comment: Two spheres are tangent if and only if the distance between their centers is equal to the sum of their radii.